# How to get the status of VGA device

Tags: unix, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

Currently I am using [vga2usb device](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/vga2usb/) for capturing output from the virtually any VGA source such as tab or any another monitor.

If I connect this vga2usb device to my Ubuntu machine then we are getting device nodes in the /dev directory.

Now I have to check that vga2usb is connected to any VGA device or not (means it is active or not). I referred following links

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-tool-for-automatically-applying-randr-configuration-when-external-display-is-pl

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469828/how-to-create-a-callback-for-monitor-plugged-on-an-intel-graphics

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/how-can-i-detect-when-a-monitor-is-plugged-in-or-unplugged

But I didn't get any specific solution for it.So how can I find the status of VGA device.
Is there any specific command or script or utility that we can use.

Comment: This is basically a coding question. It entirely depends on what interface the video grabber provides. All you found are people concerned with the other direction—output, that is.

Comment: @DanielB if don't mind can you provide some `explanation or any link `so that I can understand it

Comment: There is nothing to explain or link to. Ask the manufacturer or check whether Video4Linux has a flag like that. Again: You are not dealing with an output.